# How can I populate UICollectonView with images from the internet?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have no problem populating the `UICollectionView` with local files. The problem comes when I try to use images taken from the Internet.

I've tried downloading images using this code:

```
var images: [String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {

        for var i=1; i<160; i++ {

            var image = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://www.image.com/imagenumber\(i)")

            images.append(image)

        }
    }
}
```

I get an error in the append line saying: `"Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list type of '(NSURL?)'`.

Here is the code of the `UICollectionView` is here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row] as String)
    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), it is the go-to library for this case.

Comment: Any tutorials for this using Swift? I can't seem to find anything!

Answer (score 0):

This line will only give you the URL of the image, not the image itself:

```
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://www.image.com/imagenumber\(i)")
```

It will be of type `NSURL`, so clearly you won't be able to store it in an array of images.

You could do this:

```
if
  let imageUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "www.picture.com/url"),
  let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl),
  let image = UIImage(data: data) {
  // append the image here
}
```

First, you get the `NSURL`, then the `NSData` from the address, which can be used to initialize your `UIImage`. The reason for the multi-binding here is that the `NSURL`, the `NSData` and the `UIImage` init methods are all failable.